# Creating 2D array of chars as bits in order to calculate parity bit (C)

Tags: c, encoding, parity

I have a chunk/buffer of 49 bits (6 bytes + 1 bit) and I want to create a 2D matrix of them (7 rows,7 columns) and calculate parity bit in the 2D method in order to create encoded 8x8 bit array.

Other than iterating on every byte and add a parity bit , is there anyway to create a 2D array of bits and access them?

I'm coding in C.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far. How do you have your chunk of data? In a variable?

Comment: I'm reading a file with fread() (can be any file, now i'm focusing on txt files) , reading 49 bytes each time into a buffer: 
while (fread(Buffer, 1, 49, fp) != 0)
Then, I'm taking only 49 bit - 7 bytes with taking only the MSB of the 7th byte. Then I need to take these 49 bits and caluclate their parity in the 2-D method, which means that there should be parity bit for 7 bits 'horizontally' and parity bit for 7 bits 'vertically'.Hope that's clear - any idea?